# Set the same environment variables on all containers of the same pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I would like the set the same env variable to the same value on all the containers of my pod. I am not trying to pass info between containers so this variable will not be updated but I want to ensure that if somebody update its value, it will be kept in sync across all the containers in my pod.

Is there any way to do this out of the box? Currently I see two options:

- The ugly one would be to set the value on one container and use a `fieldRef` on the others.
- The less ugly would be to create a new ConfigMap and use envFrom in all the containers.

But Pods being a "single unit" it seems odd that there wouldn't be a way to define "pod-wide" env variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways.

1. The most common practice is as you mention using `ConfigMap`. This way is explain in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).
2. Another option is to use [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables), however it's similar to `ConfigMap` way.
3. If you know that variable before deploying, you can [Define an environment variable for a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container)
4. Last method is to set them manually in each container, however it's harsh way.

There is also a good comparsion of passing `environmental variable` in [medium article](https://medium.com/@caboadu/environment-variables-4-ways-to-set-them-in-kubernetes-bc7c8ceb333d).